# Wordpress thumbnail cropping not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added the following code to my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function add_custom_sizes() {
    add_image_size('featured-thumbnail', 690, 500, true);
    add_image_size('secondary-thumbnail', 460, 236, true);
    add_image_size('related-thumbnail', 360, 262, true);
    add_image_size('true-thumbnail', 337, 209, true);
    add_image_size('search-thumbnail', 208, 130, true);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', add_custom_sizes);
```

Within my template I have code such as:

```
<?php
      if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('featured-thumbnail');
      } else { ?>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/690x500" alt="">
<?php } ?>
```

And this is the image it outputs:

```
<img width="690" height="407" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../image-2440x1440.jpg" class="attachment-featured-thumbnail size-featured-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />
```

The original size of the image is 2440px x 1440px so I don't understand why it's not respecting my height category. It's a brand new image that's been uploaded, but just to double check I've regenerated my thumbnails but the problem persists. I'm at a complete loss. I literally just banged my head against my desk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because everything is working as it should, there is no problem / bug / issue.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's preserving your aspect ratio

2440 / 1440 = 1.694

690 / 407 = 1.695

Comment: Shouldn't the hard crop be overwriting that?

Comment: @itsclarke - nope.  Since 407 is less than 500, there's nothing to crop. The hard crop would come into effect if the aspect ratio made the image _taller_ than 1.695, but it doesn't.  Try it out.  (Think this all the way through, BTW - what seems obvious / clear about how it should work _is not_ actually that simple - I have to think about it often!)

Comment: It will crop, but that's not what you are asking it to do. You are asking it to distort the image. Increase the value of the width to something which would result in a height of greater than 500px and it will then crop it

Comment: it ended up being a setting that needed changing on the AWS S3 plugin I was using. Code-wise, everything functions as it's supposed to, it had nothing to do with the aspect ratio.